# How to compile using LoopTools in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the following tool for C++ which is called LoopTools: http://www.feynarts.de/looptools/

It basically gives a numerical value for some integrals.

The [manual](http://www.feynarts.de/looptools/LT215Guide.pdf) says that in order to use it I must:

> Like in the Fortran case, it saves a lot of typing to specify the location of LoopTools
> once in an environment variable. For example, in the tcsh, use
> `setenv LT $HOME/LoopTools/(hosttype)`
> Then compile the programs that use LoopTools with the following command: `$LT/bin/fcc -I$LT/include (source files) -L$LT/lib -looptools`

I tried doing this with the example code they provide:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clooptools.h"
int main() {
ltini();
cout << B0(1000., 50., 80.) << endl;
ltexi();
}
```

I saved this code as "example.cpp" and tried compiling it using what they said, namely:

```
g++ example.cpp $LT/bin/fcc -I$LT/include -L$LT/lib -looptools
```

But I get the following

```
.../LoopTools-2.16/x86_64-Linux/bin/fcc: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do?

Comment: What you should do is to figure out if you downloaded the right binary for your operating system. Are you attempting to run this on a 64 bit Linux distribution? Perhaps you should also reconsider downloading random binary off the Internet, and running them on your computer, in the first place.

Comment: They want you to use `$LT/bin/fcc` as a compiler, not `g++`.

Comment: Ok, I figured out it should actually be `$LT/bin/fcc -I$LT/include -L$LT/lib64 -looptools`, actually.

@HolyBlackCat Now I tried compling it as `$LT/bin/fcc example.cpp -I$LT/include -L$LT/lib64 -looptools` and now I get the following errors:


```/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccsFqRan.o: in function _GLOBAL__sub_I_first_try.cpp':

/usr/include/c++/11/iostream:74: undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::Init()'

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccsFqRan.o: in function __static_initialization_and_destruction_0':

/usr/include/c++/11/iostream:74: undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::~Init()' ```

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think I did download the correct one, especially since there is only one link available for download. This tool is also available for Mathematica and I've used it with no problems, but I am trying to use it now on C++

Comment: If `fcc` is the equivalent of `gcc` then it'll try to compile it like C program, not a C++ program, and would not link the libraries used by `<iostream>`.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it works with the following changes (Ubuntu 20.04, x86_64, LoopTools-2.16).

1. Insert the following line,

   ```cpp
   using namespace::std;
   ```

   to your `example.cpp`, before the use of `cout`/`endl`.
2. In `$LT/bin/fcc`, at line 19, remove the `-stdlib=libstdc++` compiler flag from the `cxx` variable, which seems invalid for g++:

   ```bash
   cxx="${REALCXX:-g++ -O3 -g -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -fPIC -Wall -m64}"
   ```
3. In `$LT/bin/fcc`, at line 53, add `.cpp` as a C++ file suffix:

   ```
     *.cc|*.cpp)
   ```

   Otherwise, you need to rename your example file to `example.cc`.
4. As you noticed, the library is installed into `$LT/lib64` on 64-bit Linux. Compile the program with

   ```bash
   $LT/bin/fcc -I$LT/include example.cpp -L$LT/lib64 -looptools
   ```